# Error while connecting to sql database

Tags: mysql, database, ubuntu, web-server

I am trying to access a sql database remotely. The database and the server are on two different ips. i have tried commenting out bind-address line and all the other things people have suggested in different posts but am still unable to connect to the `sql database`.

m using on my server ..

```
$ mysql -u name -h server-address -p
```

and am getting.

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'ip' (111)
```

Note: I have already granted all privileges to the specific user name and the web server and sql database is on ubuntu server.

```
SQL EXCEPTION : Failed to link account
```

Comment: Is mysqld running?

Comment: yes it is running and listening on port 3306

Comment: What about firewalls?

Comment: I dont have any firewall installed.

Comment: where as my service provide have one and they said so they have opened port 3306. Can it be still off ?

Comment: May be the user you try to connect with it is not allowed, so try to add/modify the you user you connect with it with your IP address you connect from.

Comment: I have added 4 users on the same ip address and have granted them all privileges. 
but still i cannot connect to the database it sometimes say link failure.

Comment: @Nothat The ip addresses that you add, brlongs to the host that your users connect from? Also, can you post the error message.

Comment: If you have access to nmap from your client, run "nmap server-address" and see if it shows port 3306 as "open".

Comment: @SIFE .. yup. it is the ip address from which my user tries to connect.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1420839/775849 the errorcode you have is the same as in the link. Try the solutiosn provided there?

Comment: @Jasonw.. as i have already mentioned commenting out the bind-address line did not work for me..

Comment: @phatfingers..  it only shows 2222 port opened but i have other ports opened too cant see them.

Answer (score 1):

The (111) in parenthesis gives you what's wrong. (Access denied)

[This page on MySQL.com](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/access-denied.html) covers this issue fairly extensively, I'd start there.

Chances are there's something off with the host part of your grants;

Answer (score 1):

You may need to just simply grant access.

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'MY_USERNAME'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MY_PASSWORD'

mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON 'MY_DATABASE'.* TO 'MY_USERNAME'@'12.34.56.78' IDENTIFIED BY 'MY_PASSWORD';
```